# Regarding Creating a subset using R

Tags: r, subset

I have following data frame using R.

```
 x1=c("57134967","57165081", "57217613" ,"57218874","57134965","57165061", "57218613" ,"57258874")
        x2=rnorm(8,0,1)
        data=data.frame(x1,x2)
    > data
        x1         x2
1 57134967 -3.0263640
2 57165081  1.7009238
3 57217613 -1.3100084
4 57218874 -1.6156933
5 57134965  0.1192811
6 57165061 -0.8933975
7 57218613 -0.3558627
8 57258874  0.5548350
```

I have another variable `x3` that contains a subset of values of `x1` in `data`

```
x3=c("57165081","57218874","57165061")
```

Now I need to get a subset from `data` such that the values of `x1` in `data` not equal to `x3`.

I tried the following, but it is not working.

```
data[which(data$x1!=x3)]
```

Can anybody help me to figure out how to do this correctly ?

Thank you

Comment: When you want values in `x1` that is not equal to `x3` why are you comparing with `x2` ?Try `subset(data, !x1 %in% x3)`

Comment: @RonakShah it was a typo. yeah it is working